# How to merge large number of changes info common repo?

Tags: git, git-merge, pull-request, git-merge-conflict, git-fetch

There are two developers working on branches `dev1` and `dev2`, respectively, and usually every time one of them commits a change they do a PR into a common `dev` branch.
Both developers have made a bunch of big changes, some of which may affect the same files.

Developer 1 has done a PR and merged their changes into `dev`. Now Developer 2 wants to merge their changes into `dev` as well but is worried there will be conflicts.

Rather than just doing a PR from `dev2` into `dev`, what's the best way for Developer 2 to see what the result of this merge will be?
For example, should they checkout `dev2` locally and do a `git fetch` from `dev`, and then fix any merge conflicts? Or do a `git merge` from `dev2` into `dev`?

Comment: "what's the best way for Developer 2 to see what the result of this merge will be?" → by performing the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the procedure I would recommend:

1. Dev2 merge from common `dev` to `dev2` branch.
2. Solve conflicts locally.
3. Do a pull request from `dev2` branch to common `dev` branch. (There won't be any conflicts because they have been resolved in the previous merge.)

Tip: when merging from common `dev` branch into yours it is easier to accept all remote changes and only then carefully pick and apply your own changes.